# How can i successfully create a simple form using nodejs without external modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i've been working on this for a bit:

```js
/*
API 1 Docs: https://docs.genius.com/#/getting-started-h1
API 2 Docs: https://pastebin.com/doc_api
*/

let https = require('https')
//const qs = require('querystring');


function handler(req, res){
  if(req.method == "GET"){ 
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("<html><body><form action='/' method='post'><input type='text' name='hello'><input type='submit'></form></body></html>");
  } else if(req.method == 'POST'){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(`<html>Success Posting!</html>`)
    /*
    var body;
    req.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
      if (body.length > 1e6) {
        // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
        req.connection.destroy();
      }
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
      var POST = qs.parse(body);
      let data = POST.submit
      res.end(`<html>${data}</html>`)
    });
    */
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
  };
};


https.createServer(handler).listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error starting https server');
  } else {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
  };
});
```

(Please ignore commented code)
I had it working before and all of a sudden, it stopped working, it created a form and upon submitting it it would change the page to "Success Posting" but now all of a sudden its not and ive been making small changes not knowing my problem

Comment: *I had it working before and all of a sudden, it stopped working* ... comparing the working code with non-working - what did you change?

Comment: thats the thing, i tried reverting it back to its original state but i must have missed something @Bravo

Comment: what errors do you see in the browser console? you're using `https` - do you have a valid SSL certificate etc? please define "it stopped working" a bit better - what do you see, how does that differ from what you expect. By the way, using `http` instead, your code works fine - at a guess, you had http, and changed to https, without understanding what else needs to be done for https

Comment: There are no errors, it simply does not work @Bravo

Comment: wow, you must be using an odd browser then - I see using http instead of https works

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I need to create an http server using the http module instead of making an https server with the https module

Before:

```js
const https = require('https')

https.createServer(handler).listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error starting https server');
  } else {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
  };
});
```

After:

```js
const http = require('http')

http.createServer(handler).listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error starting http server');
  } else {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
  };
});
```